# Why can't I use the data from a GET request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the data that is returned from a get request. Nothing I do allows me to use the data *outside* of the jQuery function.

Here is my sample code.

```
function getData () {
    var i;
    $.get( 'some_url.php', function( data ) {     
        i = data;
    });           
    return i;
}

console.log(getData());
```

Here's the error:

jQuery.Deferred exception: getData(...) is undefined ...

How can access the data that is returned and use it elsewhere in my application?

Comment: I think `$.get` is async. So by the time `i` is updated, it already `return i` which is undefined.

Comment: `$.get` is an asynchronus function.Async functions don't return values

Comment: This will not work as it's an async request. Alternatively, try using promises for better readability

Comment: You can use `$.ajax` with .`async: false`